# Sync Framework - The definition of referring columns in referential relationships must match the referred columns

Tags: .net, foreign-keys, constraints, microsoft-sync-framework, composite-primary-key

I am using Sync Framework. I have two tables Organizers and Events in SQL Server as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Organizers
(   
    Id int NOT NULL,
    ClientId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(400) NOT NULL,
    [Address] nvarchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNo nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientId, Id)
)

CREATE TABLE [Events]
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    ClientId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    OrganizerId int NOT NULL,
    OrganizerClientId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(400) NOT NULL,
    Location nvarchar(400) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Organizers_Events FOREIGN KEY (OrganizerClientId, OrganizerId) REFERENCES Organizers (ClientId, Id),
    PRIMARY KEY (ClientId, Id)
)
```

To provision the client, I am running the following code:

```
SqlCeConnection clientCon = new SqlCeConnection(clientConnectionString);
SqlConnection serverCon = new SqlConnection(serverConnectionString);

var tOrganizers = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Organizers", serverCon);
var tEvents = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Events", serverCon);

var pkColumnsOrganizers = new Collection<string> { "Id", "ClientId"};
var fkColumnsEvents = new Collection<string> { "OrganizerId", "OrganizerClientId"};

var fkEvents = new DbSyncForeignKeyConstraint("FK_Organizers_Events", "Organizers", "Events", pkColumnsOrganizers, fkColumnsEvents);
tEvents.Constraints.Add(fkEvents);

var scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(ScopeName);
scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tOrganizers);
scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tEvents);

SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientCon, scopeDesc);


if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(ScopeName))
{
         clientProvision.Apply();
}
```

On running the above code, I am getting `SqlCeExpception` with message: The definition of referring columns (such as number of columns or data types) in referential relationships must match the referred columns. [  Constraint name (if known) = FK_Organizers_Events ]

Is there something wrong in the code ?

**Addition:**
PKs are correctly getting picked by `SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Organizers", serverCon)`. Same for Events table as well.

[image: tOrganizers - Quick Watch]

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this thread: [how do I create a DbSyncForeignKeyConstraint to a table with a composite Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501310/how-do-i-create-a-dbsyncforeignkeyconstraint-to-a-table-with-a-composite-primary)

this is an issue on the way the PKs are picked up rather than how you're adding the FKs.

Comment: PKs (Id and ClientId in my case) are correctly getting picked by SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Organizers", serverCon). See added Quick Watch snapshot.

Comment: you're FK on the table is (ClientId, Id) which is uniqueidentifier and int... you're FK in the scope provisioning is { "OrganizerId", "OrganizerClientId"} which is int and uniqueidentifier. notice how the GetDescriptionForTable picked up the PK as Id, ClientId instead of ClientID, Id? likewise, you're actual FK definition on the table is uniqueidentifier+int for both fk and pk columns, your scope provisioning is int+uniqueidentifier.